# How do you edit nodes properties in Visual Studio 2017 DGML Editor?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, markup, directed-graph, dgml

Not sure if the editor isn't working or the documentation sucks, but I cannot seem to figure out how the heck to edit nodes.

I can add a new node, label it, and connect nodes. But I cannot add a category to the node, edit the node properties, or even re-label the node after I create it.

The cursor even focuses in on the New Category field, but when I press the keys, nothing happens.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwhM6.png)